# Excel 365 online - Locale independent text formatting of a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I try to have a text string that includes a number with a `.` as decimal separator and two decimal places, independent of the locale of the Excel the users have.

When it is just in English, `=TEXT(A1, "0.00")` works fine, and gives `1.00` when I have `1` written in **A1**.
However, when I open it on my local PC where Excel is set to German, I get an error `#VALUE!`.

Any way to make this independent of the language Excel is set to, as there are multiple people from different countries and companies working/looking at the same excel files.

I cannot use VBA.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=excel+locale+decimal

Comment: unfortunately, not very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As local-independent formatting may be impossible without VBA, you
could perhaps adapt your Excel code to become multi-locale.

The idea is to use
[VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
on a value that will change based on the system language.

The example below will use the local name of the month of
January to identify the locale as English or German for the
formatting of a date field:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(1,"MMMM"),{"January","yyyy-MM-dd";"Januar","jjjj-MM-tt"},2,FALSE)
```

In English the month is called "January", but in German it's "Januar".

We do the VLOOKUP on the parameter array below to get the right format
string:

```
"January" , "yyyy-MM-dd" ;
"Januar"  , "jjjj-MM-tt"
```

You could also store the right format string for the locale in
a cell and use this value in all the TEXT functions of this
data-type, instead of repeating the VLOOKUP call on each.

(This answer is based on the StackOverflow post
[Locale-independent Text function in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901270/locale-independent-text-function-in-excel).)

Comment: Thank you! This worked, however I ran into a problem with the month. In German (Germany) it is Januar, but in German (Austria) it is Jänner, so I changed it to March and März, which should work for both "Germans" at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using VBA, and a named reference for the number format text string.

We then change that named reference to correspond to the required format string based on the regional settings of the user.

In your US version,

- Navigate to `Formulas => Define Name`

  - I used:  `_2Dec` for the Name and `"0.00"` for `RefersTo`
- Change your formula to `=TEXT(A!,_2Dec)`
- `Alt-F11` opens the VB Editor
- In the Project Explorer, select the project referring to your workbook
- In that project, right-click on `ThisWorkbook` and select `View Code`

Paste the code below into the window that opens

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim DecSep As String
    DecSep = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
    

On Error Resume Next 'Avoid error in case someone deleted this named reference
ThisWorkbook.Names("_2Dec").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="_2Dec", RefersTo:="=""0" & DecSep & "00"""

End Sub
```

*I know the `RefersTo` argument looks strange with all those doublequotes, but they are needed since quotes are a part of the RefersTo argument.*

The code runs when the Workbook opens, and alters the reference in accord with the decimal separator being used on the user's machine.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot use VBA in the files I work with

Comment: Then you need to update your question to state that.

Comment: @Servus Unfortunately, I know of no native method in Excel alone to change the formatting string being used within the `TEXT` function.  You will need to re-do your workbook so as to not include, in your TEXT function, numbers which must be formatted.  Perhaps have the surrounding strings placed on either side of a Cell to which you have applied the formatting.  Depending on the length of the string, and how many there are, you might be able to have it all within a cell, but that can get ijmpractical pretty quickly.  (cell number format -- `"It is "0.0" inches long"`